# Maximal elements of chain of colon ideal is prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be commutative ring with $1$. Suppose $I$ is an ideal of $A$. Define $(I:x)=\{y\in A : yx\in I\}$.
Then $(I:x)$ is an ideal and it is called *colon ideal*.

Consider set of all ideals of such form. Then it forms a poset under natural order.

My question is -

> if $(J:x)$ is maximal element of a chain in the poset then it is prime ideal?

I tried proving by contradiction.
If $ab\in (J:x)$ then $abx\in J$.
Suppose that neither $ax\in J$ nor $bx\in J$.
Then consider an ideal $K$ in $A$ such that $a\in K$. Now look at $(K:x)$ then I want to somehow contradict the maximality.

Comment: The question is unclear: ideals of such form means that one can vary the ideal $I$ and $x$ as well. Looking at your attempt it seems that $x$ is fixed and only $I$ is changing. Can you clarify this?

Comment: I forgot to mention that a maximal ideal among $(I:x)$ with $x$ fixed and $I$ variable is $A$, so this approach is irrelevant. Similarly if $I$ is fixed and $x$ variable. The things are changed in the second case if one considers all $x\notin I$.

Comment: What is the ideal $K$ in the last paragraph?

Comment: @user26857. You can vary x but not ideal. There were some mistake in my approach. Apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be a commutative unital ring. 
$(I: x)=\operatorname{Ann}_{R}(\bar x)$ where $\bar x\in R/I$ and $R/I$ is seen as an $R$-module. Of course this is $R$ if $\bar x=0$ i.e. $x\in I$. So, as is pointed out in the comments, you probably should impose $x\notin I$. 
 One can then ask if $M$ is an $R$-module and $P$ is a maximal element of the set $\Sigma=\left\{\operatorname{Ann}_R m:m\neq 0\right \}$, is $P$ prime. Indeed it is. Let $P=\operatorname{Ann}_R m_0$. Say $ab\in P$. Then $a\notin P\implies am_0\neq 0\implies\operatorname{Ann}_R m_0\subseteq \operatorname{Ann}_R am_0\in \Sigma $ since $am_0\neq 0$. The maximality forces $\operatorname{Ann}_R m_0=\operatorname{Ann}_R am_0\ni b\implies b\in P$. 
 Hopefully this answers your question to some extent.